# How can I perform mathematical operation like cos and sin in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I have a searchlocationNear function for which i pass geocoded data i need to calculate distance based on lattitude and longitude values but during the alert functions of distance it displays undefined is their any problem with my code.

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     lat1=center.lat();
     alert(lat1);
     lng1=center.lng();
     alert(lng1);
     var distance1=( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) ;
     alert(distance1);
     var searchUrl = 'example.xml';
     GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = GXml.parse(data);
       var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
       map.clearOverlays();

       var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
       sidebar.innerHTML = '';
       if (markers.length == 0) {
         sidebar.innerHTML = 'No results found.';
         map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40, -100), 4);
         return;
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that code should display anything, since you're using variables that aren't defined. In JavaScript all the math functions are under [the Math object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math). So use `Math.sin` et cetera.

Might also be worth checking if Google's Map library already contains something for calculating the distance between two points. It sounds like something they would definitely include.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Math object: `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()`

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Math object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javamath.html) which contains among others trigonometric functions.